# How can i execute my javascript function inside my jsp page

Tags: java

I have written my javascript function inside my JSP and i want to execute that function  using webclient.  Is there is any way for doing this?

```
package com.test.app;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class FinalTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);

    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://jbosstest/WebPage/Home.jsp?code=GIL&appStatus=R&AppRemarks=Finally");

    String javaScriptCode =  "funcCPDiv('Insert')";

    Object result = page.executeJavaScript(javaScriptCode).getJavaScriptResult();
    System.out.println(result);
  }
}
```

Below is the error which I am getting while running my code

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
    com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.TextPage cannot be cast to
    com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage
    com.test.app.FinalTest.main(FinalTest.java:11)
```

Someone told me to use `HTMLUnit` but I am not able to understand how can I use it with a my simple example which I have mentioned above. I have tried with connection url of Java but it is not executing my javascript function it is just returning me HTML content.

Comment: You need to copy & paste content of your generated JSP page first. I bet that some kind of error occured and it might not be HTML.

Comment: This is not the same code that produced the specified error. The ClassCastException says WebClient.getPage() is returning a `TextPage` which you're erroneously trying to cast to a `HtmlPage`. However, that's not what the included code is doing. Michal is probably right, the URL is likely not returning HTML as expected.